# how to set up typeConverte attribute in json provider in apache cxf

Tags: json, cxf

Any one has some idea about how to set typeConverter attribute for the provider in bean.xml in apache cxf. I want to set the default type for all the element to be string. i.e.; I want all my values to go withing double quotes in json format to the device.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

In your beans.xml setup jsonProvider as follows:

```
<bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JSONProvider">
        <property name="convertTypesToStrings" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Add this as a provider in your jaxrs:server section

```
<jaxrs:server...
    <jaxrs:providers>
       <ref bean="jsonProvider"/> 
   </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but the problem is I am using Apache CXF 2.2.7 and in that version, JSONProvider doesn't have the property convertTypesToStrings. So, I can't set the property in bean.xml. This field is available in CXF version > 2.2.7. I am restricted to use 2.2.7. So, plz share any solution based on this version.